# Adding common wire to for smart thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat

When I look at my thermostat there are 4 of 5 wires/ terminals used— red, yellow, green, white.  There is a fifth wire (blue) unused.  When I look at the furnace side the terminals are R,C, G, W1 and W2. There is no Y terminal.  The C wire(brown)from the furnace connects to the yellow wire at the thermostat. The two W wires go to W, R to R and G to G. The Blue wire from the thermostat is capped. In addition there is a second Red and Yellow wire connected to each other but they are not directly connected to the furnace board. Is this for outside AC unit?  Can I splice my blue wire to the brown wire to make a C wire?

Comment: Please keep in mind that while the LETTERS are significant, the colors are not.  If you need to connect to C, why don't you just use the existing connection?  I find your question confusing, so you may want to edit your question and clarify what you are asking about.

Comment: To help clarify your question add a simple drawing showing each wire and the connection at each end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your unit have air conditioning?  The G wire (green) is "Call for Fan" and the Y wire (yellow) is "Call for air conditioning".  Furnaces make heat not cool.  They have nothing to contribute to air conditioning, except for running the fan to push air around (hence the G wire).  The call for A/C goes to the unit outside, hence I would expect the Y wire not to go to the furnace at all.